# Can regex capture groups be used recursively?

Tags: vi

I have a large tab-delimited file consisting of a two columns with the second column consisting of a number of subdelimited records

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| rec1 | field1;field2;field3;field4 |
| rec2 | field1;field2 |

I need it to look like

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| rec1 | field1 |
| rec1 | field2 |
| rec1 | field3 |
| rec1 | field4 |
| rec2 | field1 |
| rec2 | field2 |

The number of subdelimited fields varies from one to over 200.

I know I can do it by writing a program, but what I'd like to do is construct a regex that captures the first field at the beginning and replaces all the semicolons with \r\1 so I wind up with the record number followed by each subdelimited record on separate lines.

If I try a vi expression like

```
^\(.*\t\)\([^;]*\);/\1\2\r\1/g
```

it replaces only the first occurrence. Is there a way to construct the expression in a way that will replace all of the semicolons as desired?

Comment: This is not possible with a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it in a single regexp, but you could do it using
the following macro:

Record into the q register: Where `^M` is a literal press of the enter key,
`^R` is literally pressing ctrl+R, and `^I` is a literal press of the tab key.
(Not shown is me pressing the escape key to exit from insert mode back to
normal mode):

```
"xyiwf;s^M^Rx^I
```

This yanks the first word into the `x` register, then finds the next semicolon
and substitutes it with a newline, pastes the yanked word from the x register,
and puts a tab.

Then you can repeat that macro on all lines with a semicolon like so:

```
:g/;/norm 200@q
```

Each repeat will 'consume' one semicolon, until there are none left (so just
put however many you need (200+).